# boost::thread within a class

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I'm trying to have a class that when created, starts a background thread, similar to that below:

```
class Test
{
  boost::thread thread_;
  void Process()
  {
    ...
  }

  public:
    Test()
    {
       thread_ = boost::thread(Process);
    }
}
```

I can't get it to compile, the error is "No matching function for call to boost::thread::thread(unresolved function type)". When I do this outside of a class it works fine. How can I get the function pointer to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should initialize `thread_` as:

```
Test()
  : thread_( <initialization here, see below> )
{
}
```

`Process` is a member non-static method of class `Test`. You can either:

- declare `Process` as static.
- bind a Test instance to call `Process` on.

If you declare `Process` as static, the initializer should just be

```
&Test::Process
```

Otherwise, you can bind an instance of `Test` using Boost.Bind:

```
boost::bind(&Test::Process, this)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you want to initialize boost::thread with a pointer to a member function.

You would need:

```
Test()
    :thread_(boost::bind(&Test::Process, this));
{

}
```

Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546319/boostthread-compiler-error) may be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Process method static:

```
  static void Process()
  {
   ...
  }
```