# Pass address of struct type to boost::thread?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, boost-thread

Using Boost 1.43 threads, the following is compilable:

```
void MyClass::threadFn(...) { ... }
void MyClass::doFn(...) {
    ...
    boost::thread(&MyClass::threadFn, this, ...);
}
```

But the following is *not* compilable:

```
void MyClass:doFn(...) {
    ...
    struct MyStruct {
        MyStruct(...) { ... };
    }

    boost::thread(&MyStruct, ...);
}
```

This yields `'MyClass::doFn::MyStruct': illegal use of this type as an expression`. Note that I am not trying to pass a pointer to an instance of `MyStruct`; I am trying to pass the type itself, as I would a function pointer, so that `boost::thread` will invoke the constructor of the type.

According to [The Boost 1.43 Threads Spec](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html):

> A new thread is launched by passing an object of a callable type

So how do I pass the address of the `struct` type to the `boost::thread` function (AFAIK this would also apply to `boost::bind`)?

[Further reading on how to accomplish this with functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361244/error-c2064-term-does-not-evaluate-to-a-function-taking-0-arguments-thread-hpp)

Comment: MyStruct is not a *callable* type. You need to define a function which operates upon a MyStruct and then use that function to instantiate the thread instead.

Comment: Also, you're missing a semicolon, and `MyStruct` isn't even in scope at the desired line.

Comment: @user931794: How do I do that? I can't instantiate the MyStruct in the function, because the operations performed by MyStruct need to be started in a new thread.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Edited to include the semicolon; how is `MyStruct` not in scope at the desired line? The compiler thinks it is and recognizes it as an invalid type. (The actual code is far more complex than this - typos in this example are not actually from my code.)

Comment: @taz: Oh, sorry, that's true - it is in scope, but it's a local class. In C++03, those can't be template arguments.

Comment: (Also, please don't type examples. Paste them from your minimal, self-contained, compilable code on your machine.)

Comment: @KerrekSB I would normally make a SSCE but I cannot afford to take time out for it. Is C++03 the standard before C++11? What does Visual Studio 10 use? (Googling right now but haven't found yet)

Comment: @taz: VS10 has partial support for C++11; but then you should also be using `std::thread` in preference over Boost.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm not familiar with preferring `std::thread` over Boost. Does boost require C++11 implementation? I thought Boost was implemented into C++11.

Comment: @user931794's comment says it all. user931794: You should make it an answer (and perhaps explain what _callable_ means, just to be sure).

Comment: @taz: With C++11, you don't need Boost for threads. You can simply `#include <thread>` and use `std::thread`. It has the same interface.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was under the impression that a lot of boost was incorporated into C++11. However my platform is Visual Studio 2010, which does not use C++11 AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyStruct is not a callable type. You need to define a function which operates upon a MyStruct and then use that function to instantiate the thread instead.

A thread is an execution context, and to instantiate one you need a set of instructions for it to execute.

In Java, we see this in the form of a Runnable, which is used to instantiate a Thread, which can then be `start()`ed.

In C/C++ with Boost, you must use a function pointer.

The term "callable type" translates roughly into "type which is exchangeable with function pointer."

If you want to operate on an arbitrary struct, as in your example, `MyStruct`, you first must define a set of instructions ( a function ) which operates on that type.

Once you know the set of instructions, you can pass a pointer to that function to intantiate a thread, and then run that thread with arbitrary instances of MyStruct.

Code follows:

```
struct MyStruct {
        MyStruct(...) { ... }
    };

int frobnicateMyStruct( const MyStruct& msr ) {

    /* some operations on msr */

    return 0;
}    

void foo() {

    MyStruct myStructInstance;
    boost::thread(&frobnicateMyStruct, myStructInstance);

    /* ... */

    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks for those fixes. I like having the autos in my code to remind me about their storage class but I can see why you took them out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what the purpose is, but the following would call `MyStruct()`:

```
boost::thread(boost::bind(boost::value_factory<MyStruct>()));
```

You can pass arguments also, for example with `MyStruct(int i, int j)`:

```
boost::thread(boost::bind(boost::value_factory<MyStruct>(), 1, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
boost::thread(&MyStruct, ...);
```

Invoke an instance:

```
boost::thread(MyStruct(), ...);
```

Comment: This would still require `MyStruct` to be callable. i.e. `(MyStruct())()`

Comment: `Note that I am not trying to pass a pointer to an instance of MyStruct; I am trying to pass the type itself, as I would a function pointer, so that boost::thread will invoke the constructor of the type.`

Comment: @taz - a function pointer is not a type. You can't pass a type to `boost::thread`. You can write a function that constructs a `MyStruct` object, and pass that function.